# android gdb error: "Cannot access memory at address"

Tags: android, gdb

- Target: Android 4.1.2, device: Google Nexus S, gdb server version: 7.3.1-gg2
- Host: cygwin, gdb version: 7.3.1-gg2

ndk-build, using `NDK_DEBUG=1`

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1-gg2
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i586-pc-mingw32msvc --target=arm-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
0x4008fa40 in ?? ()
(gdb) set solib-search-path obj/local/armeabi
(gdb) warning: while parsing target library list (at line 2): No segment defined for org.cocos2dx.wgame
warning: while parsing target library list (at line 2): No segment defined for org.cocos2dx.wgame
file obj/local/armeabi/libwgame.so
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
Reading symbols from R:\code\wondergame\wgame\proj.android/obj/local/armeabi/libwgame.so...done.
(gdb) list
(gdb) Cannot access memory at address 0x37fc28
```

When I insert a breakpoint, `gdb` states "Cannot access memory at address"

please help me